# how does conda check packages for compatibility?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, anaconda, conda

In my environments created with anaconda, the same packages installed with conda are not compatible when I try to install with pip.

Is there a difference how pip and conda handle dependencies?

Here an example of requirements.txt

```
# Python version 3.9.13

django==2.2.5
djangorestframework==3.14.0
gensim==4.1.2
joblib==1.1.1
nltk==3.7
numpy==1.21.5
openpyxl==3.0.9
pandas==1.4.4
pickleshare==0.7.5
scikit-learn==1.1.3
seaborn==0.12.0
spacy==3.3.1
tensorflow==2.9.1
unidecode==1.2.0
```

conda allows you to create the environment, pip reports incompatibility between django and djangorestframework.

Comment: Could you post an example, like `requirements.txt` for pip and [`conda-lock` file](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/lockfile) from conda, that show incompatibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Conda checks, if all packages that will end up in the environment are compatible with each other and tries to find the optimal solution - considering all package versions.
2. Pip is less strict and only checks, if the new package is compatible with the existing ones. It doesn't change versions of the previously installed packeages.
3. Pip installs packages from from pypi.org, while conda installs from anaconda.org. The packages are not exactly the same, since the Anaconda staff  authors new packages and tries to increase their compatibility with the older ones.
4. However, sometimes you are not interested in 100% compatibility but just want to use the latest features. Then pip is good enough because your unit tests will tell you if something goes wrong.